# Use a variable as key name in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array with subarrays in a loop. In each iteration there must be an array_push, and after the loop I want save the array. The array must be looks as follows:

```
Array => (
    "pa_attribute1" => Array(
         'name' => 'pa_attribute1',
         'value' => 'value',
         'is_visible' => '1',
         'is_taxonomy' => '1'
    ),
    "pa_attribute2" => Array(
         'name' => 'pa_attribute2',
         'value' => 'value',
         'is_visible' => '1',
         'is_taxonomy' => '1'
    ),
    "pa_attribute3" => Array(
         'name' => 'pa_attribute3',
         'value' => 'value',
         'is_visible' => '1',
         'is_taxonomy' => '1'
    ),
)
```

The 'problem' is, that the name of key is a variable. So, "pa_attribute1, "pa_attribute2" and so on, are the result of a function, and I 'don't know' the result, so I can't program all the possibilities. 
Is there a function available what I can use to create an new array with a variable as key? Like this?

```
$result = array();
for($i=0; $1 < $length; $i++){

    $value = get_attribute_name();

    $value = Array();

    array_push($result, [array]);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). All the [answers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) you need are there. [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is not what you need.

Comment: `$result[get_attribute_name()] = [whatever];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `array_push()`, you can add elements directly:

```
for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++){

    $result[get_attribute_name()] = [array];

}
```